# ASP.Net MVC 3 ListBox Selected Items Collection Null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox

I have a pretty simple scenario and I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious. I'm trying to use a ListBox to grab multiple Id's and add them to my model, but no matter what I do, the collection is always null. Here's the code:

The model collections:

```
public IEnumerable<Model.UserProfile> TravelBuddies { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<int> SelectedTravelBuddies { get; set; }
```

I populate the TravelBuddies collection in my controller.

The view code:

```
<div class="module_content">
@if (Model.TravelBuddies.Count() > 0)
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedTravelBuddies, new MultiSelectList(Model.TravelBuddies, "Id", "FullName"))
}
else
{
    <span>You don't currently have any travel buddies (people who were with you on this trip). Don't worry, you can add some to this trip later if you'd like.</span>
}
</div>
```

The select list is populated in my view. No problem there. But once I select multiple items and submit my form, the Model.SelectedTravelBuddies collection is always null. Am I missing something obvious? It's been a long night of coding.

**Update: Added Controller Code**

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult New()
        {
            Model.Trip trip = new Model.Trip();
            ITripService tripService = _container.Resolve<ITripService>();
            IUserAccountService userService = _container.Resolve<IUserAccountService>();

            int userProfileId = userService.GetUserProfile((Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey).Id;

            trip.TripTypes = new SelectList(tripService.GetTripTypes(), "Id", "Name");
            trip.TravelBuddies = userService.GetTravelBuddies(userProfileId);

            tripService.KillFlightLegTempStorage();

            return View(trip);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult New([Bind(Exclude = "TripTypes")] Model.Trip trip)
        {
            ITripService tripService = _container.Resolve<ITripService>();
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                tripService.KillFlightLegTempStorage();
                return View(trip);
            }

            int tripId = tripService.CreateTrip(trip, (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);
            tripService.KillFlightLegTempStorage();

            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Trip", new { id = tripId });
        }
```

Comment: Whats your controller look like?

Comment: Updated to show the controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you are binding to SelectedTravelBuddies. When your list is rendered, what is it's name? It's been a long night for me too :) want to make sure it matches the model. Also are you sure the list is in the form element so they are posted?

Comment: The rendered list name and id is SelectedTravelBuddies and the name and id values are correct. My assumption is that the binder would bind the selected values of TravleBuddies to the SelectedTravelBuddies collection.

Comment: Oh man. I should have called it a night a long time ago. I didn't have that ListBox in the form. What a rookie mistake. I knew it was something obvious. Works just great now ;) Thanks for the help.